# How to get magento user phone number?

Tags: magento-1.9, permissions, user-roles, user

I have created a user and given some admin role permissions, i want to get this user details like phone number etc, how can i get this?

```
$roles_users = Mage::getResourceModel('admin/roles_user_collection');
        foreach($roles_users as $roleuser):
          $user = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->load($roleuser->getUserId());
          $role_data = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->load($user->getUserId())->getRole()->getData();//print_r($role_data["role_name"]);die;

          if ($role_data["role_name"]=="callcentre"){
            echo '<br/>User : '.$user->getUserId()."|".$role_data["role_id"]."|".$user->getUsername()." | ".$user->getFirstname()."|".$role_data["role_name"]."|";
          }
        endforeach;
```

Comment: We will need to know how you added these new fields to the admin user model. Normally they should be loaded when the object is loaded but without knowing how they are added I am not sure someone will be able to help you here.

Comment: Correct i haven't added this fields yet, is it possible to add phone number in it?

Comment: Yes i have created a phone number field in the admin user form, then how can i get the phone number from there?